# xamarin android cannot modify file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building an app where I have to open a file from my application modify it and then save it in the same path. Here is the code for that action.

```
await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest()
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath)
}
```

I have also enabled the external storage read and write permissions by adding them in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The problem is that whenever the launcher opens the file it opens it in readonly only mode which does not allow me to save the file in same directory, but rather to another path after modification.
I have also set the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` property to `true`.
I want to able to edit and save the file in the same path that was used to open by calling the `Launcher.OpenAsync` method.

Comment: What's the error log of this problem?  Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: The above method did not trigger the file observer events properly. I am using Android.OS.FileObserver on the same file the launcher opens and some of the events are not triggerd.